# Angular - toggle class in dynamic elements on click

Tags: angular, dom, click, dom-events

I want to toggle right and wrong classes but unable to do it. Boolean value is coming from array and on condition It add class on all the elements.

I want, red background class when it finds wrong answer and green bg class when answer bit in array is true.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?
Working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4yczgp

**HTML**

```
<div class="question-row custom-block-question" *ngFor="let item of qblock.options;let j = index"
             (click)="validateAnswer(item)"
             [class.post-correct-answer]="item.id == id && rightMcq"
             [class.post-wrong-answer]="item.id == id && wrongMcq">
          <div class="option-wrapper">
            <div class="qitem">

              <div class="qitembox">{{ item.optionLabel }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="qitem-text">
              <div class="qitem-textbox">
                <p>
                  {{ item.optionText }}
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

**TS**

```
validateAnswer(item) {
    this.id = 0;
    this.wrongMcq = false;
    this.rightMcq = false;
    console.log('clicked', item);
    if (item.optionActive === true) {
      this.id = item.id;
      this.wrongMcq = false;
      this.rightMcq = true;
      console.log('this is true');
    } else {
      this.id = item.id;
      this.wrongMcq = true;
      this.rightMcq = false;
      console.log('This is false option');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your option, they don't have id. So item.id is undefined and your this.id in your click event is undefined, that's why it will color every items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `id` property to the values. You were right in checking `item.id == id` in the `[class...]` condition, but there was no `id` property in the `item` to begin with. So I've assigned random IDs 1 through 8.

Try the following

```
this.practiceQuizData = [
  {
    index: 4,
    questionType: 1,
    questionNumber: 'Question 1',
    questionText:
      'Question 2',
    options: [
      {
        optionLabel: 'A',
        optionText: 'Option A',
        optionActive: false,
        id: 1
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'B',
        optionText: 'Option B',
        optionActive: false,
        id: 2
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'C',
        optionText: 'Option C',
        optionActive: false,
        id: 3
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'D',
        optionText: 'Option D',
        optionActive: true,
        id: 4
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    index: 5,
    questionType: 1,
    questionNumber: 'Question 2',
    questionText:
      'Question 2',
    options: [
      {
        optionLabel: 'A',
        optionText: 'Option A',
        optionActive: true,
        id: 5
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'B',
        optionText: 'Option B',
        optionActive: false,
        id: 6
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'C',
        optionText: 'Option C',
        optionActive: true,
        id: 7
      },
      {
        optionLabel: 'D',
        optionText: 'Option D',
        optionActive: false,
        id: 8
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b5umna)

Comment: Hey @Michael D, can you please help me with another issue?

Comment: @Kenny.k: Please post the link to the question. I'll try to solve it if I can.

Comment: This is my partner’s issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840491/angular-check-if-all-options-are-selected-to-enable-button