# Angular - Check if all options are selected to enable button

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, click, angular-directive

This is a quiz app, in this scenario my next button will redirect to another page and **it's disabled by default**. **If I choose all the options it should enable**.

**NOTE:**

My functionality of selecting options and choosing correct/wrong is working fine, I just can't figure out **how to enable when each single option is selected.**

Any help or suggestions?
Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5qtyxy

```
buttonDisabled = true;
```

```
<button class="btn-next" [disabled]="buttonDisabled">
  Next
</button>
```

Comment: it doesn't matter, if the user selects the correct answers, right ?

Comment: Yes. Means, no answer should be unselected or left you can say. Otherwise user can’t proceed. I hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on this is to define the `buttonDisabled` as a getter and then evaluate for each question if it's status allows for the navigation to the next page...

In my implementation the user has to select all of the answers of the type-2-questions, but only one answer on the type-1-questions. If this is not what you want please state so in the comments, it's just what appeared logical to me. I hope it helps you already.

Any questions? Just ask.

[Here's my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cezwml)

Answer (score 0):

you can use Object.keys for that, like this

App.component.html

```
<button class="btn-next" [disabled]="isDisabled()">
    Next
  </button>
```

app.component.ts

```
isDisabled(): boolean {
  return Object.keys(this.answerEvaluation).length !== Object.keys(this.practiceQuizData).length;
}
```

Comment: It enables 2-3 options earlier, why is that?

Comment: The button becomes active when all 5 questions are answered

Comment: Right now, in your case it becomes active when I click on last option. Meaning, if i have selected all other question’s answers and then click on any option of remaining question, it enables the button. Can you please help with that

Comment: Please edit in stackblitz, you can better understand what I’m trying to say

Comment: try my version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yuozwg

Comment: Yes same case is happening, which I discussed.

Comment: Clicking on first option of last remaining question, enables it. Why is that?

Comment: it is activated when at least one answer of each question is selected. it's not what you want ?

Comment: No, each option of each question, sorry if I was unclear

Answer (score 0):

The answers will work, but you can make it the Angular way shown here:

https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

There are 2 ways:
template-driven or reactive forms

Then you can bind disabled property to the form valid property.

Choose what’s suits best to your needs. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I think this would work but won’t editing what I have made take time?

Comment: Yes, it will raise taken time. Therefore you may consider this the next time, when building  forms.